# NTFS access very slow , perhaps a hang

Tags: performance, ntfs

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 about a month ago. Very nice. I dual boot it with Windows and have run it on VirtualBox. I hope to transition from Windows to Linux this year. I have many files in various NTFS partitions on multiple drives. They all show up and look right. However, today while browsing the files I ran into a problem. I opened a 278GB NTFS partition that contains many pictures and videos in various folders. When I went to a subfolder containing 48675 files, the app window showed the first N entries but became unresponsive so that I could not scroll. I was in "list" view and could see in the "size" column that for some of folders it said "nnnn entries". For others it said "..." or something like that. While I watched one of the folder size fields changed from "..." to "2716 entries". It seemed that the file viewer app was looking at every file directory entry on this logical drive and doing so very slowly. I waited 10 minutes. I went to close the window but Ubuntu said it was not responding and asked me if I want to force it to close. I cancelled the close, and instead minimized the window. When I tried to reopen it a minute later it would not open. I then shut down and noticed that during shutdown there was a brief error message mentioning error/interrupt #15.

Back in Windows, I ran a check of that drive partition. No errors were found. It is fully defragmented. In Windows I can navigate the files on that drive very quickly. Can anyone suggest a fix? This could be a showstopper for my migration to Linux. TIA for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned it contains photos.
Nautilus might be generating thumbnails for your files hence the hang

try this in terminal

```
ls 'your directory location here'
```

and see if you geting list of entire files contained without hanging

or else try another file manager called thunar

```
sudo apt-get install thunar
```

its pretty fast and has inbuilt multiple renaming feature

Comment: also see to it you have ntfs-config installed and configured for ur ntfs drives

PS: you may need to run the following command on terminal
sudo mkdir -p /etc/hal/fdi/policy

to run ntfs-config correctly

Answer (score 0):

The first time you open a ntfs dir with images or videos it tends to be as slow as it would be in windows when it is generating thumbnails.

Just like Windows 98, XP or 7 you should restrict the number a files to no more than 10.000 images (or 1gb) (1000 avis's) to avoid the read dir lag, monstrous thumbnailing work (that tires your disk!).

It also prevents corruption of directories. In big dirs Be aware of long file names !

This is from my own experience !